# Fix an element to the right edge of an overflowing container

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, overflow

I am trying to create an indicator of horizontal scrollable content that only shows when an overflow occurs.

The red square, which will be the indicator that there is overflowed scrollable content, but I cannot find a way to get it to stay fixed to the right scrollable edge.

```css
.rpt {
  display: inline-grid;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.rpt::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #b00;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.rpt .rpt-row {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  height: 50px;
}

.flx-item {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rpt">
  <div class="rpt-row">
    <div class="flx-item">
      <span>Lipsum</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flx-item">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="flx-item">
      <span>12345</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flx-item">
      <span>25</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flx-item">
      <span>1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flx-item">
      <span>0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flx-item">
      <span>0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flx-item">
      <span>0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flx-item">
      <span>0</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would prefer not to alter HTML if possible, but am open to using JavaScript if CSS cannot achieve this alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is `position: sticky`, not `absolute`, but the parent has `display:grid`, so you need to add `grid-row-start: 1` to both the indicator and the first row make them overlap instead of creating another row.

```css
.rpt {
  display: inline-grid;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.rpt::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #b00;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}

.rpt .rpt-row {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  height: 50px;
}

.rpt .rpt-row:first-child {
  grid-row-start: 1;
}

.flx-item {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rpt">
  <div class="rpt-row">
    <div class="flx-item">
      <span>Lipsum</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flx-item">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="flx-item">
      <span>12345</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flx-item">
      <span>25</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flx-item">
      <span>1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flx-item">
      <span>0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flx-item">
      <span>0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flx-item">
      <span>0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flx-item">
      <span>0</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: if you want the indicator to span all row it's some what tricky with auto row template because currently [CSS can't get the last auto-generated line](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2402). If you can be sure that the number of rows never exceed a limit (for example, 100), you can do this:

```css
.rpt::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 30px;
  background: #b00;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
  grid-row: 1/span 100;
}
```

If you can't find such a magic number then maybe try changing the HTML structure or using JS to update the number of rows:

```js
//Call this function when finish loading and when rows are added/removed
function countRows() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.rpt').forEach(function(ele) {
    const rows = ele.getElementsByClassName('rpt-row').length;
    ele.style.setProperty("--rows", rows);;
  });
}

function addRow() {
  const ele = document.querySelector('.rpt');
  ele.appendChild(ele.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true));
  countRows();
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  countRows();
});
```

```css
.rpt {
  display: inline-grid;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.rpt::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 30px;
  background: #b00;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
  grid-row: 1/ span var(--rows, 100);
}

.rpt .rpt-row {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  height: 50px;
}

.rpt .rpt-row:first-child {
  grid-row-start: 1;
}

.flx-item {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="addRow()">Add 1 row</button>
</div>
<div class="rpt">
  <div class="rpt-row">
    <div class="flx-item">
      <span>Lipsum</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flx-item">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="flx-item">
      <span>12345</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flx-item">
      <span>25</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flx-item">
      <span>1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flx-item">
      <span>0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flx-item">
      <span>0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flx-item">
      <span>0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flx-item">
      <span>0</span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I knew sticky was the answer but I couldn't get a working solution. In your answer you have used `grid-row-start` to position the element but the indicator needs to span all rows. Do you have any ideas to achieve this?

Comment: @DreamTeK is the number of rows fixed? Can rows be added/removed by user action?

Comment: Unfortunately not. So I need the box to fit the 100% height of the "rpt" div

Comment: Great detailed answer. Thank you for your efforts.